# Question about interpretation of Quran

Tags: discussion

My question basically asks if Muslims are so single minded mind about Quran and that this is the truth while their belief itself rest on the fact that Quran is right, how can they interpret Quran right. Isn't it possible they will leave out all errors, contradictions? I have simply provide context of my question to reinforce what I wanted to ask

[Can any Muslim interpret the Qur'an accurately?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/is-quran-wrongly-interpreted)

Why would this be closed when Islam starts from understanding of the Quran?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment when I closed it, the issue isn't the content of the question.  The problem is that the question, as worded, meanders and seems to ask different things as it progresses; it is very difficult to tell what is and is not relevant in the context, as it is very difficult to tell what is and is not actually being asked.  As such, the question as phrased is ill-suited to this site.

Fix the post to emphasize the *actual question*, and I will consider reopening it.

Comment: When the real question is in the title, and re-asked it in the last paragraph. Some of the emphasis in the middle is just to make the point why interpretation can be wrong. So the answer can address those issue as well if they think it is appropriate.

Comment: re emphases the question in the end.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: "Is Quran wrongly interpreted?", "How can a Muslim interpret Quran right?", "Can Muslim possibly interpret Quran in it real context when he is so single minded, and when his belief trust in the fact that Quran is right?" and "Can he possibly say Quran was not clear about this so it is Quran mistake not mine?".  Four distinct questions on my last readthrough. And that isn't even counting the ones that (I felt) were obviously rhetorical.

Comment: I you find it rhetorical, I have no problem you closing it :)

Comment: I have cut out all context of the question. In my opinion this is not as an interesting question now but at least I removed all controversial part.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter it was better with the context, that was never the problem.  the problem was, and still is, the fact that it is not clear *what you are actually trying to ask*.

Comment: please explain what are you not clear about. I am saying Quran can be grossly mis interpreted if you start to read from the point of view that it cannot contain any error and you you are not in a position to deny anything because they will make you kafir.

Comment: I think I got you concerns. For me it was crystal clear but for you, it was not obvious enough. It is good we clarified and the question is now open.

Answer (score 3):

I think the tone was bad and it is not good even after the edit.

You are putting presumptions in a form that implies you have your answer and making a criticism, not really asking a question.